# Plate traveling at constant speed in rarefied gas

Tags: statistical-mechanics, kinetic-theory

I'm trying to understand [this article](https://www.airitilibrary.com/Publication/alDetailedMesh?docid=05779073-201304-201305230016-201305230016-189-199). A plate moving inside a rarefied gas, with speed comparable to the speed of the gas particles. Drag force is modeled as the difference of pressure on both sides due to the collisions of the plate and the particles. Now, the "correct approach", as I see it, would be to work in the reference frame of the plate. Then we work as we would inside a regular gas, except that the velocity distribution is skewed, translated by a vector $\mathbf{v}$; just integrate for every velocity.

The argument I don't understand from the article is:

> If we view the situation from the mean reference frame of the molecules, the motion of the plate related to the molecules is then described by the relative speed $\mathbf{v_r}$. That is, in this reference frame, we can assume that all molecules of the gas are at rest and the plate moves through the gas with a speed given by the average relative speed between the plate and the gas $\mathbf{v_r}$.

Of course, no such reference frame exists. In fact, the initial reference frame is the one in which the mean velocity is zero already.

My result is close to the one in the article, so there must be some merit to that approximation. Why does it work?

Answer (score 0):

Going only by what you have quoted$^1$, I think the authors are simply stating that a plate moving through stationary air is the same as air blowing on a stationary plate.

The mean reference frame that they talk about is the frame moving with the average of the velocities of all air particles. If the air isn't moving - no wind, this frame is at rest wrt. lab.
If there is a wind, this frame is moving realative to lab.

Now if the plate is also moving relative to lab, by switching to the air's frame (wind or not) and giving the plate an apt relative velocity and assuming that all air particles are frozen in space$^2$, they commit no crime.

As you explain, in the plate's ref. frame, the air acquires the relative velocity instead.

---

$^1$ I couldn't download the paper
$^2$ Since the plate is moving with speeds comparable to the molecules.